# Expanding dense information in cell across multiple rows

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame as follows:

```
A tibble: 6 × 4
  ID     Country   Info      City 
  <chr>  <chr>     <chr>       <chr>
1 001    USA      Supported   New York;San Diego;
2 002    UK       Supported   London;Manchester;Swansea 
3 003    India    Approved    Mumbai;Chennai;
4 004    Canada   Supported   Montreal;
5 005    Italy    Approved    Rome;;;
6 006    Germany  Supported   Frankfurt;Hamburg;Munich
```

I am hoping to expand the `City` variable so it looks like this

```
A tibble: 12 × 4
   ID     Country   Info      City 
   <chr>  <chr>     <chr>       <chr> 
1  001    USA      Supported   New York
2  001    USA      Supported   San Diego
3  002    UK       Supported   London    
4  002    UK       Supported   Manchester    
5  002    UK       Supported   Swansea 
6  003    India    Approved    Mumbai       
7  003    India    Approved    Chennai 
8  004    Canada   Supported   Montreal
9  005    Italy    Approved    Rome 
10 006    Germany  Supported   Frankfurt 
11 006    Germany  Supported   Hamburg 
12 006    Germany  Supported   Munich
```

I have tried to use `mutate` and setting a True/False on a second dataframe to no avail.

```
cities <- expand_grid(Country = c("USA", "UK", "India", "Canada", "Italy", "Germany"),
               City = NA)

cities %>%
    mutate(Found = City %in% data$City)
```

Does anyone have any method to expand the final column?

Comment: You could use something like `data %>% tidyr::separate_rows(City, sep = ';')`.

Comment: @14314520 Worked perfectly!